# Finding the sub-algebras (up to conjugation) of $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the connected subgroups of the Lie Group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ up to conjugation. My thought was to find the sub-algebras of the Lie Algebra $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, and then exponentiate. For the one dimensional sub algebras, it should just be determined by the Jordan form. I am a little stuck with the 2-dimensional sub algebras.

I think that the answer should just be 
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\0 & -a \end{pmatrix}: a,b \in \mathbb{C}\right\} $$

but i'm not sure how to prove it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is correct. It follows from the fact that any $2$-dimensional subalgebra automatically is a Cartan subalgebra, and these are conjugate. But probably there is a more direct way to see it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I would have thought that Cartan subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ are 1-dimensional. Maybe you mean Borel subalgebras?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, of course. What a silly mistake.

Comment: Douglas and Repka have classified all subalgebras even up to inner automorphism, see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02028.pdf), along the lines, within the proof for $\mathfrak{so}_4(\Bbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})\times \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft This might be a dumb question, but how do you know any 2-D sub-algebra is automatically a Borel sub-algebra?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the source, I will read it over.

Comment: A Borel subalgebra is by definition a maximal solvable subalgebra. But any $2$-dimensional Lie algebra is solvable, and since the algebra itself is not solvable, it will thus be a maximal such subalgebra.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!